# How to include Biography with photo in springer format

Tags: graphics

I used this, but it is not working the way IEEEbiography works. Please help me out.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}        
\AtBeginDocument{                   
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}}
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \newcommand*{\authorimg}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
    \includegraphics[
      height=\baselineskip,
      width=\baselineskip,
      keepaspectratio,
    ]{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{biography}
{
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{BioPic.png}
}
\textbf{Author name}
........
\end{biography}


\begin{biography}
{
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{BioPicSir.png}
}
  \textbf{Author Name} ...
\end{biography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. To help you we need to understand the problem and the best way to do that is to recreate it on ower machine. Please give us a Minimal Working Example wich is code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so that we could try and compile it and see what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is better, however, we still don't have the llnc class, nor the pictures in question. Are they crucial or can we use article and examples images from graphix?

Comment: Also, you are using the biography environment. I could not figure out where that was defined (the llnc.cls I found had no such definition). IEEEtrans has a definition of IEEEbiography. 
Do you wish to define a new environment, or simply create an apendix biography section with a floating image?

Comment: Well, I tried to use IEEEbiography but it is not suitable with springer format, so I had to use the biography tag.

Comment: Which biography tag? `biography` environment is not defined in llncs. Please clarify your question. Do you have a biography environment that is defined but does not work or do you want to recreate a biography environment that resembles that of the IEEETrans?